# Is the software in Linux Mint software manager trustworthy?

Tags: linux-mint, security, package-management

Are the packages of Linux Mint going through any form of manual review before being submitted to the software manager?

I am asking becuase application that should be downloaded many times like discord only have 53 reviews, and application like Rider only have 2. Is there someone that looks into this packages, and verfies that they are indeed coming from the correct source and are not trojan?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reviews have nothing to do with security, it's not a popularity contest. Package maintainers get the source code for the packages they create from the applications source code repository, like github, gitlab, sourceforge, etc.

Mint has 3 primary sources for their packages, first, Debian sid package pool, which is where Ubuntu gets many of its packages from when they build next ubuntu. Second, Ubuntu makes many of their own packages. Third, Mint creates some of its own packages as well.

You may be confusing Windows total and complete lack of security when installing programs, aka, packages, from random and various sources, over which the person installing the software generally has very little idea about who is creating the executable, who is distributing it, etc. None of those issues exist in the GNU/Linux package repositories, you know who created the package, an approved packager, who are fairly tightly controlled by Debian (becoming an official Debian packager is quite difficult), Ubuntu (likewise, to become a primary Ubuntu packager is not easy), and lastly Mint, who I don't know much about in terms of how they control their packagers. I assume similar to Ubuntu, more or less.

The packager, and this is regardless of the package manager type, apt, pacman, ports, whatever, it's all roughly the same, goes to the project home source code repository, and, generally speaking, clones of pulls from the repo, and uses that code to build their package.

This package, after passing the distro package testing protocols (Debian's is most strict of all distros I am aware of), is then sent to the distro package pool, for testing and debugging (this is what Debian sid's package pool is for, finding and fixing bugs with newly introduced versions of existing packages). This is controlled by a system that only allows signed / securely admitted packages into the package pool, and is done over secure channels.

I would say the fact that you believe that the number of reviews a package has in a gui package manager (I assume this is where you saw that, since 'reviews' per se don't actually exist in any package manager I've ever touched), which has NOTHING at all to do with the packager, the package, or the package pool, absolutely zero, suggests you may have a somewhat fundamental confusion about what security actually is.

The process of this tightly controlled chain, which is, say in the case of github, ssl/ssh connection to github, program author commits changes to github repos, over secure systems, github controls the source code, then the distribution packager grabs that source code, using equally secure channels, builds the package, then submits it to the distribution package pool manager, the 'ftp master' in the case of Debian, where it is verified, with package hashes verifying the submitted package is the same as the original package, then it enters the pool, where it is grabbed by the local system, say your computer, and used by its package manager, which will also verify the signature of the package (I believe it does, pretty sure), then install it.

Now, obviously, if you install random 3rd party repositories, very common in for example Ubuntu with their PPAs, or Arch Linux with their AUR, then the security plummets since you have much less control over that specific person and their technical and security competence, but even there in general I'd take an AUR package (which are generally created straight from git sources) over a random windows download and install .exe file, of which you know precisely zero in terms of its lineage, transmission chain, or anything else.

So the issue you're worried about here is actually one of the best reasons to use linux in the first place, and to skip things like snap, flatpak, or other package installers that bypass this entire system of security and control as much as possible, unless they also come from primary verified and known reliable sources, making them much more similar to a windows .exe or an apple .dmg file than a Linux or BSD package created by a packager for the distribution.

Package managers run by a distribution with verified package maintainers creating the packages are one of the very top reasons to use Linux if you are concerned about security. Popularity contests and votes would be one of the very worst ways to verify security I could imagine.

On a strictly technical level, and keep in mind, this applies to any method of creating an installable binary, .exe. .dmg, .deb, .tcz, whatever, the single biggest risk is that the repository itself is compromised, for example, someone gains write access to the repository, and then pushes nefarious code into the project without anyone realizing that has happened. This is risk for all code, from Microsoft/Apple generated, to anything on github, gitlab, etc. But with version control systems like git, these changes can be detected and corrected, since they leave a trail in the commit histories. But that has nothing to do with the way the binary is created and the installer method for that binary.

In windows/apple systems, with their .exe/.dmg based installers, this risk is far far higher, since users in general do not have the ability to know if the download source is legitimate, have no way or understanding that would let them verify the hashes against a known good, and will generally just click the installer, click the pop up ok to install dialogue in windows, then happily install the trojan enhanced executable into windows, and never even realize they did this, or that their system is now fully compromised. Again, a reason NOT to use windows, to not use that random download and install .exe file, to bypass all the out of date and obsolete and insecure .dll's the installer includes (very similar to snap or flatpak, again).

Linux package managers take care of all this for you, it's hard to imagine a more secure out of the box system for general use in fact, which is one thing that makes the trend towards bloated insecure blobs installed via snap or flatpak so disturbing, particularly if you are concerned at all with security.

Comment: Windows now also introduced an app store - which would be as trustworthy as an official repository. Also note that in many cases one may also just download a) random `deb`-files, b) random shell-scripts or - very popular nowadays - c) just add random repositories as trusted sources. All with the same problem of lowered security.